# The given key 'members@delta' was not present in the dictionary when using using delta query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following code to read users from AAD group using Graph delta query:

```
        public async Task<IGroupDeltaCollectionPage> GetGroupUsersPageByIdAsync(string groupId)
        {
            var retryPolicy = GetRetryPolicy();
            return await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                return await _graphServiceClient
                                    .Groups
                                    .Delta()
                                    .Request()
                                    .Filter($"id  eq '{groupId}'")
                                    .Top(MaxResultCount)
                                    .GetAsync();
            });
        }

        public async Task<IGroupDeltaCollectionPage> GetGroupUsersNextPageAsnyc(IGroupDeltaCollectionPage groupMembersRef, string nextPageUrl)
        {
            var retryPolicy = GetRetryPolicy();
            return await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                groupMembersRef.InitializeNextPageRequest(_graphServiceClient, nextPageUrl);
                return await groupMembersRef
                                .NextPageRequest
                                .GetAsync();
            });
        }

        public async Task<(List<AzureADUser> users, string nextPageUrl, string deltaUrl, IGroupDeltaCollectionPage usersFromGroup)> GetFirstUsersPageAsync(Guid objectId)
        {
            var users = new List<AzureADUser>();
            var response = await GetGroupUsersPageByIdAsync(objectId.ToString());
            if (response.CurrentPage.Count > 0 && response.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData != null && response.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData["members@delta"] != null)
            {
                var deltaMembers = response.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData["members@delta"].ToString();
                var json = JObject.Parse("{\"deltaMembers\":" + deltaMembers + "}");
                var groupDeltaUsers = (JArray)json["deltaMembers"];
                foreach (JObject user in groupDeltaUsers)
                {
                    if (user["@odata.type"].ToString().Equals("#microsoft.graph.user", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                        user["@removed"] == null)
                    {
                        users.Add(new AzureADUser { ObjectId = Guid.Parse((string)user["id"]) });
                    }
                }
            }
            response.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.nextLink", out object nextLink1);
            var nextPageUrl = (nextLink1 == null) ? string.Empty : nextLink1.ToString();
            response.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.deltaLink", out object deltaLink1);
            var deltaUrl = (deltaLink1 == null) ? string.Empty : deltaLink1.ToString();
            return (users, nextPageUrl, deltaUrl, response);
        }

        public async Task<(List<AzureADUser> users, string nextPageUrl, string deltaUrl, IGroupDeltaCollectionPage usersFromGroup)> GetNextUsersPageAsync(string nextPageUrl, IGroupDeltaCollectionPage response)
        {
            var users = new List<AzureADUser>();
            response = await GetGroupUsersNextPageAsnyc(response, nextPageUrl);
            if (response.CurrentPage.Count > 0 && response.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData != null && response.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData["members@delta"] != null)
            {
                var deltaMembers = response.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData["members@delta"].ToString();
                var json = JObject.Parse("{\"deltaMembers\":" + deltaMembers + "}");
                var groupDeltaUsers = (JArray)json["deltaMembers"];
                foreach (JObject user in groupDeltaUsers)
                {
                    if (user["@odata.type"].ToString().Equals("#microsoft.graph.user", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                        user["@removed"] == null)
                    {
                        users.Add(new AzureADUser { ObjectId = Guid.Parse((string)user["id"]) });
                    }
                }
            }
            response.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.nextLink", out object nextLink1);
            nextPageUrl = (nextLink1 == null) ? string.Empty : nextLink1.ToString();
            response.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.deltaLink", out object deltaLink1);
            var deltaUrl = (deltaLink1 == null) ? string.Empty : deltaLink1.ToString();
            return (users, nextPageUrl, deltaUrl, response);
        }
```

On running this, I see the following exception:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'members@delta' was not present in the dictionary.
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

On looking more into this issue, what I noticed is that on running delta query in demo tenant, this is what I see as result:

{

```
"@odata.context": "",

"@odata.deltaLink": "<delta-link>",

"value": []
```

}

if there are no new members.

In prod, this is what I see:

```
{

 

"@odata.context": "",

    "@odata.deltaLink": "<delta-link>",

    "value": [

        {

            "classification": "",

            "createdDateTime": "",

            "creationOptions": [

                "<option1>"

            ],

            "description": "",

            "displayName": "",

            "expirationDateTime": "",

            "groupTypes": [

               

            ],

            "mail": "",

            "mailEnabled": true,

            "mailNickname": "",

            "preferredDataLocation": "",

            "proxyAddresses": [               

            ],

            "renewedDateTime": "",

            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],

            "securityEnabled": false,

            "securityIdentifier": "",

            "visibility": "Private",

            "id": ""

        }

    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`members@delta` property which is relationship on users is not included in all delta query requests.

You need to check if `response.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData` has this property.

Resource:

[Resource representation in the delta query response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#resource-representation-in-the-delta-query-response)